# Trying to use namespace in launch file for launching rviz2 but the model is not spawn

Tags: ros2, rviz, roslaunch, ros-foxy

I'm trying to use namespace to spawn robot in rviz2 nodes in multiple times, however the spawned rviz2 show only TF but no 3d model of the robot. The error is here.

```
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1697114086.385679041] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1697114086.385801449] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1697114086.410083025] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[joint_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1697114086.518128010] [phantom_ns.joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
```

My launch file is here

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
import xacro

# this is the function launch  system will look for
def generate_launch_description():

    ####### DATA INPUT ##########
    urdf_file = 'phantom.urdf'
    package_description = "moonbot_description"

    ####### DATA INPUT END ##########
    print("Fetching URDF ==>")
    robot_desc_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory(package_description), 
        "urdf", 
        urdf_file
    )


    phantom_ns = LaunchConfiguration('phantom_ns')

    phantom_ns_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'phantom_ns',
        default_value='phantom1'
    )
        # description='Top-level namespace')


    # Robot State Publisher
    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher_node',
        emulate_tty=True,
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True, 'robot_description': Command(['xacro ', robot_desc_path])}],
        # parameters=[robot_description],  ## for xacro
        namespace = phantom_ns,
        output="screen"
    )

    # Joint State Publisher
    joint_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        namespace = phantom_ns,
        output='screen'
    )

    # RVIZ Configuration
    rviz_config_dir = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory(package_description), 
        'rviz', 
        'urdf_vis.rviz'
    )


    rviz_node = Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        name='rviz_node',
        namespace = phantom_ns,
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True}],
        arguments=['-d', rviz_config_dir]
    )


    # create and return launch description object
    return LaunchDescription(
        [           
            phantom_ns_arg,
            robot_state_publisher_node,
            rviz_node,
            joint_state_publisher_node
        ]
    )
```

Can someone guide me what I need to fix. I'm using ros2 foxy. Thank you.